# How to find the angle here?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle. $AB=AC$ and $D$ is a point in the triangle. $DBC=25, DCB=10, CAB=110$. How much is the angle $ADB$?

Comment: Are $25$, $10$, $110$ angles in degrees?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes, there're in degrees

Comment: Are you sure you've given the correct lengths? I've obtained $\angle ADB\approx160.44º$ which doesn't look very nice for a geometry problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some angle-chasing, we repeatedly use the sine rule in various triangles. Since: 
$$\angle ABC=\angle ACB=35^\circ,$$  $$\angle ABD=10^\circ,$$ 
and $$\angle ACD=25^\circ;$$ So by using the sine rule: $$\sin 10^\circ=\frac{AD}{AB}\sin\angle ADB.$$ Similarly, $$\sin 25^\circ=\frac{AD}{AC}\sin\angle ADC,$$ and $$AB=AC\implies\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{\sin 25^\circ}{\sin 10^\circ}=\frac{\sin\angle ADC}{\sin\angle ADB}.$$ But we also have $$\angle ADB+\angle ADC=215^\circ,$$ so $\angle ADB\approx 160.44^\circ$ as per @Dr.Mathva's comment.